# Sharing data between module.config(...) and a directive -- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-formly

I need to share a variable between the module's config function and a directive. We are using angularJS and formly.js in combination with Kendo UI.

The custom templates for formly are defined in our module's config function but the implementation is stored in a directive.

When the dropdown's onChange event is triggered in the directive, I need to be able to pass an object from there back to the module config to power another function.

The point of this is that my client wants an icon next to every input to clear its contents easily. Whether you agree/disagree with their decision doesnt matter, I already tried to change their mind and they want this so here goes.

Here is some of the code:

```
app.config(function config(formlyConfigProvider) {

    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
        name: 'InputObjectDD',
        wrapper: ['horizontalInput', 'bootstrapHasError'],
        template: function (objAssets) {
            var tmpl = '<drop-down-directive lookup-key="{{to.lookupKey}}" lookup-field="{{to.lookupField}}" 
                lookup-required="options.templateOptions.required" field-id="{{options.key}}"
                field-value="{{to.displayField}}" ng-model="model[options.key]"></drop-down-directive>
                <i ng-click=\'deleteInputContents(dataItem)\' class="k-icon k-i-close"></i>'; },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.deleteInputContents = function (dataItem) {
            // Clear the drop downs input
        }
```

And in the directive where the Kendo dropdown itself is defined, I need to pass the dataItem variable in a way that the deleteInputContents() above can access it.

```
select: function (e) {
                        var cmb = this;
                        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
}
```

If anyone can think of a way to achieve this or an alternative approach, I'd be eternally grateful.

Things I already tried:

- Create a service to pass the data. This doesnt work as you cannot access a service in the modules config function
- Store it as a global on root scope. This didnt work for me either as I couldnt access the root scope from the modules config function

Comment: So, if you have access to the `dataItem` when you create the field (where you say: `type: 'InputObjectDD` and your other field options), you could pass the `dataItem` in on `templateOptions` and use that in your template.

Comment: God damn I'm dumb, thanks that's awesome